# Adding multidimensional array to another array

Tags: php, arrays

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp), this should work:

```
// A two-dimensional array:
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",100,96),
  array("BMW",60,59),
  array("Toyota",110,100)
  );
```

Then how come the following code doesnt:

```
$json = [];

foreach ($res as $product) {
    $slur = $product['slur'];

    $node = [
        'description' => $product['description'],
        'colors' => $product['color'],
        'region' => $product['region']
    ];

    var_dump($node); // Node has proper values

    $json[$slur] = $node; 
}

var_dump($json); // Keys are fine, $product['region'] works, colors and description don't
```

My $node var_dump:

```
array(3) { ["description"]=> string(128) "Ac risus eu amet rhoncus cursus, rhoncus in amet nascetur, diam, elementum porttitor penatibus nec cum dignissim proin et augue." ["colors"]=> string(67) "gun-blue, gun-green, gray-black, gun-orange, gun-lightblue, gun-red" ["region"]=> string(6) "europe" } array(3) { ["description"]=> string(128) "Ac risus eu amet rhoncus cursus, rhoncus in amet nascetur, diam, elementum porttitor penatibus nec cum dignissim proin et augue." ["colors"]=> string(67) "gun-blue, gun-green, gray-black, gun-orange, gun-lightblue, gun-red" ["region"]=> string(3) "usa" } array(3) { ["description"]=> string(128) "Ac risus eu amet rhoncus cursus, rhoncus in amet nascetur, diam, elementum porttitor penatibus nec cum dignissim proin et augue." ["colors"]=> string(19) "pink, green, purple" ["region"]=> string(6) "europe" } array(3) { ["description"]=> string(128) "Ac risus eu amet rhoncus cursus, rhoncus in amet nascetur, diam, elementum porttitor penatibus nec cum dignissim proin et augue." ["colors"]=> string(103) "black, red, silver, blue, green, gunmetal, brightgreen, gold, lightblue, darkblue, orange, pink, purple" ["region"]=> string(6) "europe" } array(3) { ["description"]=> string(128) "Ac risus eu amet rhoncus cursus, rhoncus in amet nascetur, diam, elementum porttitor penatibus nec cum dignissim proin et augue." ["colors"]=> string(67) "gun-blue, gun-green, gray-black, gun-orange, gun-lightblue, gun-red" ["region"]=> string(3) "usa" } array(3) { ["description"]=> string(128) "Ac risus eu amet rhoncus cursus, rhoncus in amet nascetur, diam, elementum porttitor penatibus nec cum dignissim proin et augue." ["colors"]=> string(67) "gun-blue, gun-green, gray-black, gun-orange, gun-lightblue, gun-red" ["region"]=> string(3) "usa" } array(3) { ["description"]=> string(128) "Ac risus eu amet rhoncus cursus, rhoncus in amet nascetur, diam, elementum porttitor penatibus nec cum dignissim proin et augue." ["colors"]=> string(67) "gun-blue, gun-green, gray-black, gun-orange, gun-lightblue, gun-red" ["region"]=> string(6) "europe" } array(3) { ["description"]=> string(128) "Ac risus eu amet rhoncus cursus, rhoncus in amet nascetur, diam, elementum porttitor penatibus nec cum dignissim proin et augue." ["colors"]=> string(67) "gun-blue, gun-green, gray-black, gun-orange, gun-lightblue, gun-red" ["region"]=> string(3) "usa" }
```

My $json var_dump:

```
array(5) { ["alignmee"]=> array(3) { ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["colors"]=>     string(0) "" ["region"]=> string(3) "usa" } ["xl"]=> array(3) { ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["colors"]=> string(0) "" ["region"]=> string(3) "usa" } ["hybrid"]=> array(3) { ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["colors"]=> string(0) "" ["region"]=> string(3) "usa" } ["classic"]=> array(3) { ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["colors"]=> string(0) "" ["region"]=> string(3) "usa" } ["original"]=> array(3) { ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["colors"]=> string(0) "" ["region"]=> string(6) "europe" } }
```

I can't really understand what i'm doing wrong. Can anyone please explain?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This works fine for me when I create a dummy `$res` array with the appropriate keys.  So as @sebcap26 said, what is `$res`?

Comment: $res is a list of products. $product['description'] also returns proper values.

Comment: I think above commentors want a `var_dump($res);`. At least i would want one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) in PHP to actually construct an JavaScript JSON String, by taking an PHP Array and passing that through it.

```
//Instigate the $json array, otherwise it'll throw a notice.
$json = array();
foreach ( $res as $product ) {
    $slur = $product['slur'];
    $node = [
        'description' => $product['description'],
        'colors' => $product['color'],
        'region' => $product['region']
    ];
    //We use the [] here to append to a new index
    //on each iteration of the loop; otherwise, it'll overwrite the last value
    $json[$slur][] = $node; 
}

echo json_encode( $json );
```

Secondly, probably equally as important!

- *Don't* learn from w3schools, Check out [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com)
- *Do* Use [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/)

Comment: @R.vanderPeijl No Problem! if you need any clarification on anything, let me know =)!

Comment: How does adding [] solve the problem when $slur is already supposed to be a different value on each iteration? And why does this (even if it would add a new array item) help filling description and region?

Comment: As @ToBe said, I still don't really understand why `$json[$slur][]` works and `$json[$slur]` doesn't.

Comment: @R.vanderPeijl the `[]` notation is a just a shorthand for [`array_push()`](http://uk3.php.net/array_push), otherwise `$node` will overwrite whatever is placed inside the `key` of `$slur`; now I think this all stems from the fact that, actually your first `var_dump` doesn't display any key of `slur`..

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the output it is clear that the data is being overwritten in your while loop

So try this

```
$json[$slur][] = $node;
```

instead of

```
$json[$slur] = $node;
```

if you want to add only the node which a have color and description then you could try the following in your foreach loop

```
if(!empty($product['description']) && !empty($product['color']) ){
 $node = [
        'description' => $product['description'],
        'colors' => $product['color'],
        'region' => $product['region']
    ];

}
```

Comment: can you add your var_dump output

Comment: @R.vanderPeijl - The comments section is not ideal for large blocks of code. Please add it to your question instead, then delete the comment. That way it is more visible to others (and you can apply formatting)